# type of expanded C macro

Tags: c, macros, petsc

What type and value does PETSC_COMM_WORLD in the following header expand to? 
Is it just a redefinition for `MPI_Comm` with `extern` scope?

```
#define PETSC_EXTERN extern PETSC_VISIBILITY_PUBLIC

PETSC_EXTERN MPI_Comm PETSC_COMM_WORLD;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple text substitution, so you end up with:

```
extern PETSC_VISIBILITY_PUBLIC MPI_Comm PETSC_COMM_WORLD;
```

Hence the type of `PETSC_COMM_WORLD` is `PETSC_VISIBILITY_PUBLIC MPI_Comm` and so depends on the definition of `PETSC_VISIBILITY_PUBLIC`, which hasn't been provided.

From a cursory search of the net, it will be empty when *building* the `petsc` DLL or the attribute `__attribute__((visibility ("default")))` when *using* it.

The `extern` itself doesn't control or modify the type (nor does that attribute for that matter) it simply states that this variable is not being *created* here, but should be made available elsewhere.

The *value* depends entirely on where you're defining the variable, what scope it's at, whether you initialise it, and so on.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation; from one MPI implementation, I was expecting `MPI_COMM_WORLD` and similar to be an integer constant, fixed after configuration. I am interested in fishing out its value at compile time (I'm wrapping this library in a different language), what's the idiomatic way of doing it? Thanks again

Comment: @ocramz, you can use something like `gcc -E yourfile.c | less` to have it output the translation unit _after_ the preprocessing step. That should give you all preprocessed symbols. Microsoft has the `/P /C` options which will give you a `yourfile.i` file containing the preprocessor output (with comments left in).

Comment: Thank you again; I'm on a Unix; however the configure/build is quite involved (a very large makefile); I was wondering if there's perhaps a way of writing a thin C wrapper that exposes functions that return only the value of these constants..

Comment: @ocramz, that's possible as well, such as putting at the start of `main`: `if (argc > 1) { if (strcmp (argv[1],"xyzzy")==0) { printf ("Value of PLUGH is %d\n", PLUGH); return 0; } }`, then running your code with `myprog xyzzy`.